# Static member type or nothing in Julia

Tags: julia, nifti

Just trying to get my head around Julia and came across the need where a type member should be of a particular type or it can also be `nothing`. So, I tried the following:

```
using NIfTI  # Julia package for reading NIfTI medical images

type RR
    source::Union(NIfTI.NIVolume, nothing)
end
```

However, when I try to initialize this object, I get:

> ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching
>   Union(::Type{NIfTI.NIVolume}, ::Void)

The reason I want to do this is that there is no good default way to initialize the `NIVolume` object and it seems a good idea to leave it uninitialized till needed.

Comment: there is a [`Nullable`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types.html#Constructing-[Nullable](@ref)-objects-1) type in julia.

Comment: @Gnimuc Ahhhh missed that. Thanks for pointing that out. Why could I not use that `Union` though? I guess it is implemented as a function and only for certain types?

Comment: you could, use `Union{NIfTI.NIVolume, Void}`.

Comment: btw, it seems that `NIfTI.jl` provides [a default way](https://github.com/JuliaIO/NIfTI.jl/blob/af8c3cdfd84c886c12ed3e6d7d6d0862d3a91293/src/NIfTI.jl#L280-L364) to init `NIVolume`.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this. I literally just started to use Julia yesterday. So could not figure out how to initialize this. I also extended the class to have 3 NIVolume members and now I have to in initialize it as `r = RR(Nullable{NIfTI.NIVolume}(), Nullable{NIfTI.NIVolume}(), Nullable{NIfTI.NIVolume}())` which is extremely cumbersome as well. AFAIK I cannot initialize these members with default values in the class declaration?

Comment: [these lines](https://github.com/JuliaIO/NIfTI.jl/blob/af8c3cdfd84c886c12ed3e6d7d6d0862d3a91293/src/NIfTI.jl#L280-L320) are [`optional or keyword arguments`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/functions/#optional-arguments), so you can simply init a nii object via `NIVolume()` or `NIVolume(rand(3,3,3), descrip="my nii obj")`(the first optional argument is the raw data; `descrip` is keyword argument.)

Comment: what do you mean by "in the class declaration"? ["default field values"](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10146#issuecomment-74924844) is still not supported in julia for now, we should write an outer constructor to init these values.(e.g. RR() = RR(NIVolume(rand(1,1,1))), NIVolume(rand(1,1,1))), NIVolume(rand(1,1,1))))

Comment: @Gnimuc Right. Got you! Sorry was being very stupid and a bit confused!

Comment: feel free to ask if you have any questions ;)

Comment: @Gnimuc I am sure I will have tons as more days go by... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia's type system can also express the concept that an expression cannot produce any value – e.g. if it throws an error or is part of a basic block that cannot execute (dead code). The type of an expression that can never produce a value is the empty union type, Union{}: a union of zero types, of which no values are instances. This is distinct from the type of nothing – since nothing is a normal (but uninteresting) value, so it cannot be an instance of Union{}.

http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/faq/#nothingness-and-missing-values